# Jenkins - block Merge button when Jenkins build fails

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

When I create/update (commit changes) merge request in Gitlab it is triggered POST request (webhook) to Jenkins for building my branch. Currently I am using Multibranch pipeline in Jenkins for this purpose.

**Question**: Basing on presented context - What is the best approach to block *Merge button* in Gitlab when Jenkins build fails?

I wanted to start with **Gitlab API** (close/reopen merge request) + **Gitlab plugin** (get populated variables from POST e.g merge request id) but I have read that Jenkins' Gitlab plugin is not supporting multibranch pipeline (mentioned variables are not populated) so it makes much harder to write such code.

**Thanks for help :)**